# C++: What can I use to generate sine wave patterns onto an image?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

I am looking for any C++ tools that will help me generate sine wave like fringe patterns onto a loaded image like so:

[image: Sample Output]

Any ideas using other programming modes (scripts?) would also be useful. If any more information is requested, please let me know.

Comment: This is a rather vague question to be honest. Any UI framework which allows for certain graphs could be used. If you're going the Qt route, perhaps [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/curvescreenshots.html) would be useful.

Comment: The [OpenCV Library](http://www.opencv.org) might be useful (especially [the image processing part](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/imgproc.html)).

Comment: @Bart Qwt seems to be capable of just generating the sine wave as opposed to changing the brightness following the sine wave pattern. MMoment below seems to have a handle of the idea, reading his answer may help if you're trying to gain some clarity

Comment: It was not at all clear to me that the image processing itself was your issue, rather than the illustration of the effect in a GUI as you illustrated. You might want to clearly state this in your question. Reading it again, you're right, but it's not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into OpenCV:

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html#brightness-and-contrast-adjustments

Looks like it might be of use, though I don't know if it is sufficient for your specific use case. You should be able to do it manually though.

The rendering of a sine wave would result from local brightness adjustments through calculation of the sine value for the image position relative to the period ( e.g. period == image width). I don't have any real knowledge of the library, but from telling from previous experiences with Matlab and similar tools, the brightness distribution would pixel-wise hence be calculated

local_brightness = sin(2pi*cur_pos/width)*local_brightness

If you know the color space and the format of the image you might as well do it manually, pixel for pixel like described above. In that case you could read in the image with http://libav.org/ and recalculate it.

Oh and one last general idea, given you know the image format and color space:

Generate a vector that fits the width of the target image, then calculate the sine signal relating to the x-axis and multply the resulting vector with the target image brightness?

I admit it's a long shot, but it might work for you :P

Comment: Could you explain sin(2pi*cur_pos/width)?

Comment: well, depending on whether you want to have an offset of the wave and/or a different period of the sine wave you need to vary the parameters of the sine wave calculation. This relates to the current pixel position within the image (possibly relative to the imagewidth)in one way or the other.

B_new = B_cur*sin(2*pi*(cX/tX)) would calculate the brightness B_new as a function of the current calue B_cur multiplied by the result of the calculation of a sine wave relative to the total image width with a period of the image width. This would render exactly one period of a sine wave onto the image.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to be more specific about exactly what you're looking for.  [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/), the C++ bindings for the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) library, has a lot of tools for doing various types of image processing, but depending on your needs it may or may not be able to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Greatly appreciated. What more would you like to know about? The application is a GUI, so this process should be executed from a thread